# How to connect to docker container from eclipse using jdbc

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, jdbc

I have downloaded the docker image `mysql/mysql-server` from docker hub and ran a container using the command:

`docker run --name <name of my container> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<my pwd > -d mysql:mysql-server`

I have opened `mysql` in interactive mode using command `docker exec -it <name of my container> mysql -uroot -p` and created a database, table and granted all its privileges to my machine ip using following commands:

```
mysql> create user 'uname'@'<machine ip>' identified by 'pwd'; 
mysql> create database <dbname>; 
mysql> grant all privileges on <dbname>. * to 'uname'@'<machine ip>' identified by '<pwd>';  
mysql> flush privileges;
```

I opened my eclipse and created a db connection using `data source explorer` and connected using `jdbc:mysql://<container ip>:3306/dbname`. When I test my connection it is saying:

> Connection timed out

Could any one suggest where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Please cleanup your question and make sure it is properly formatted. Note that you don't specify a port mapping in your docker run, so it isn't accessible.

Comment: Fixed grammar, formatting, and punctuation issues.

Answer (score 1):

In docker for Mac you can't access services via container ip.

In docker for Windows you can access the container ip , but you need to configure your firewall.

Best and most secure way to do this is *port-mapping* with `-p` option:

```
docker run --name <name of my container> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<my pwd > -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:mysql-server
```

Your database will be in `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname`

I recommend to use the official image (just *mysql*), instead of manually create the database.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
```

Your connection will be in `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname` also.

If this doesn't work, ensure your proxy lets you accept connections on 3306.

Comment: how to access services via container ip in mac?

Comment: I have tried the same processs you have mentioned but still getting connection timed out

Comment: CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 16b0bd5bee9e mysql/mysql-server "/entrypoint.sh my..." 2 hours ago Up 2 hours (healthy) 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp database Even though the container is up and running i am unable to access i have tried with both localhost and container ip it is showing timeout in both the cases.

Comment: it is getting the below error   Could not connect to New MySQL.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to New MySQL. (Error: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
Communications link failure

Comment: when i tried to ping my container ip it is giving below error ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1

Comment: how to access services via container ip in mac?   ... you can't https://forums.docker.com/t/access-dockerized-services-via-the-containers-ip-address/21151/2

Comment: via port mapping should work. put the docker logs of the container. Remember you must create the database again. Try to use the official image "mysql". I improve my answer to explain this.

Comment: It is not working can you tell me how to make  proxy let me accept connections on 3306 in mac

Comment: Do i need to grant permission to my machine ip for accessing container ip after running the command?                                                         
 mysql> create user 'uname'@'<machine ip>' identified by 'pwd'; 
mysql> create database <dbname>; 
mysql> grant all privileges on <dbname>. * to 'uname'@'<machine ip>' identified by '<pwd>';  
mysql> flush privileges;

Comment: it's working when i place my docker machine default ip in place of localhost in jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname

Answer (score 0):

I searched the same question over google and I found out this [access containers by internal IPs 172.x.x.x](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221)

So if you go through the thread you will find out it will work for Linux the way you want to by using container IP `localhost:3306`.

Comment: Is it possible to access the container from same machine in which eclipse is present?

Comment: Yeah as docker container have there own IP you can use docker inspect command and it will work the same.